# Request-Response logic to allow non-response messages to be processed

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, logic, communication

I have a socket application that allows thousands of clients to connect. It stores them in a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, Socket>` and operates solely for request-response situations:

- When I need data, I find the relevant socket and send a request, asking for the data I need.
- After sending the request, I receive bytes until it sends the response. Then I stop receiving.

Like this:

```
public Task<Message> Request(int clientId, Message message)
{
    Socket client;
    return Clients.TryGetValue(clientId, out client)
        ? RequestInternal(client, message);
        : _EmptyTask;
}

public async Task<Message> RequestInternal(Socket client, Message message)
{
    await SendAsync(client, message).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await ReceiveOneAsync(client).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Now I need to change this application to allow clients to send me anything, anytime; even without I make a request for it. Which -I think- will require constantly receiving from the sockets and a completely different approach.

## Questions:

1. What are the bets-known approaches (best-practices) for this kind of applications?
2. Any gotchas you can tell me about or any guides you can point me to?

---

**What I have in mind:**
*Disclaimer: This part is a little long and completely hypothetical. You can skip that if you have an answer to the above questions.*

What I have in mind:

- Receiving bytes constantly and adding the assembled PDUs to a `BlockingCollection<Message>`.
- Creating a thread, dedicated to process received messages using `BlockingCollection`'s `GetConsumingEnumerable` method.

The processing thread will do this:

```
foreach (var message in Messages.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    ProcessMessage(message);
```

With this I can receive and process everything the clients send but distinguishing the messages that are sent to reply my requests from the messages that are sent because the client needed to would be an issue.

I think I can send a unique identifier byte (unique to that particular client) with the request. Then the client can send that identifier back to me in its response and I can use it to distinguish the response.

```
ProcessMessage(Message msg)
{
    // msg is a message from msg.Sender.

    if (msg.Id == 0)
    {
        // msg is not a response, do processing.
    }
    else
    {
        // msg is a response to the message that's sent with msg.Id.
        // Find the request that:
        // * ...is made to msg.Sender
        // * ...and has the msg.Id as identifier.
        // And process the response according to that.
    }
}
```

This means I also have to store the requests.
Here is an hypothetical version of `RequestInternal`:
**Edit:** *Replaced `Wait` calls with `await`s after Stephen Cleary's answer.*

```
private async Task RequestInternal(Socket client, Message message)
{
    var request = new Request(client, message);
    Requests.Add(request);

    await SendAsync(client, message).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await request.Source.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

And the `Request` class:

```
private sealed class Request
{
    public readonly byte Id;
    public readonly Socket Client;
    public readonly Message Message;
    public readonly TaskCompletionSource<Message> Source;

    public Request(Socket client, Message message)
    {
        Client = client;
        Message = message;
        Source = new TaskCompletionSource<Message>();

        // Obtain a byte unique to that socket...
        Id = GetId(client);
    }
}
```

And `ProcessMessage` becomes this:

```
ProcessMessage(Message msg)
{
    if (msg.Id == 0)
        OnReceived(msg); // To raise an event.
    else
    {
        // Method to find a request using msg.Sender and msg.Id
        var request = Requests.Find(msg);

        if (request != null)
            request.Source.SetResult(msg);
    }
}
```

Although I have no idea what kind of collection type `Requests` would be.

**Edit:** I've used a `ConcurrentDictionary<Key, Request>` where `Key` is a private struct with an `Int32` (id of the socket) and a `Byte` (id of the message) fields. it also implements `IEquatable<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [TCP/IP .NET Sockets FAQ](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) a few years ago that addresses some common problems (such as [message framing](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html), [continuous reading](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-socket-as-connected-socket.html), and [explanations of common errors](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/error-handling.html)). The code samples all use the `Socket` class, but the same concepts apply to all TCP/IP sockets.

Regarding your protocol design and request/response matching, the overall approach sounds good. You'll need to ensure you're threadsafe (e.g., `Requests` would probably be a `ConcurrentDictionary`). Also, you should `await` `SendAsync` rather than calling `Wait`.

An alternative approach that I've played around with but haven't put into production is based on [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx). You can create one block that represents the "output" for each client and another block for the "input". Then you can layer your message framing on that, and layer your request/response matching on that, and then send any remaining (unsolicited) messages to a single shared `BufferBlock`.

So your "end-user" API would end up looking like this:

```
// Send a request and asynchronously receive a matching response.
Task<Message> RequestAsync(int clientId, Message message);

// Endpoint for unsolicited messages.
IReceivableSourceBlock<Tuple<int, Message>> UnsolicitedMessages { get; }
```

You could then hook up an `ActionBlock` to `UnsolicitedMessages` to execute a delegate whenever one comes in.